# Problema al sumar las unidades, decenas y centenas de cada elemento del vector

Tags: c#, array

tengo un problema al sumar las unidades, decenas y centenas de un vector. Mostrándolo en un ejemplo:

vector[0] = 123
vector[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNaZ4.png) = 456
vector[2] =  78

Y que en unidades salga 17, en decenas 14 y en centenas 5. Sumando en línea vertical.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (vector[i] < 10)
            {
                u = u + vector[i];

            }
            if (vector[i] < 100)
            {
                valor = Convert.ToString(vector[i]);
                d = d + Convert.ToInt32(valor[0]);
                u = u + Convert.ToInt32(valor[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                valor = Convert.ToString(vector[i]);
                c = c + Convert.ToInt32(valor[0]);
                d = d + Convert.ToInt32(valor[1]);
                u = u + Convert.ToInt32(valor[2]);
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo este problema, me salen números grandes, dónde está la anomalía?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si entendí bien tu problema.

Pero supongo que con este ingreso :

- vector[0] = 123
- vector[1]= 456
- vector[2] = 78

Y el resultado sería,

- centenas 1 + 4 = 5
- decenas 2 + 5 + 7 = 14
- unidades 3 + 6 + 8 = 17

Hice un programa en consola en **.Net Core 2.0**, el algoritmo no es a mi gusto, pero son cálculos matemáticos rápidos.

Comprobé solamente el camino feliz con la entrada que proporcionaste.

```
namespace Nueva_carpeta
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var u = 0;
            var d = 0;
            var c = 0;

            int[] scores = new int[] { 123, 456, 78};

            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                c += calcularCentenas(scores[i]);
                d += calcularDecenas(scores[i]);
                u += calcularUnidades(scores[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.WriteLine(d);
            Console.WriteLine(u);

        }

        static int calcularCentenas(int number){

            if(number < 100) return 0;
            else{
                return  number / 100;
            }
        }

        static int calcularDecenas(int number){
            if (number <= 100) return number / 10;
            else{
                int auxiliar = number / 100;
                int auxiliar2 = auxiliar * 100;
                return (number - auxiliar2) / 10;
            }
        }

        static int calcularUnidades(int number){
                if (number <= 100) {
                int auxiliar = number / 10;
                int auxiliar2 = auxiliar * 10;
                return (number - auxiliar2);
            }
            else{
                int auxiliar = number / 100;
                int auxiliar2 = auxiliar * 100;
                int auxiliar3 = (number - auxiliar2);

                int auxiliar4 = auxiliar3 / 10;
                int auxiliar5 = auxiliar4 * 10;
                return (auxiliar3 - auxiliar5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hago, es simple y básico. Es clave el uso de **Integer**.

Cualquier duda, respondo el por que del algoritmo así. Repito, no es muy agradable.

Saludos